# PHP console does not echo

Tags: php, cmd

Okay this really strange or I am missing something. When I run this very simmple PHP script  on cmd I get the expected output which is 0. but when I uncomment the last two lines of code. . .nothing is displayed.

```
<?php

    $test1  = 0;

    echo $test1;
    $test2 = 0;

    #$test1_weight = 0:
    #$test2_weight = 0;
?>
```

Is there some rule against declaring variables after an echo statement?

Comment: you got a colon : instead of a semicolon ;

Comment: lol im not wearing my glasses (hides), thanks it works now! Can you add this comment as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test1_weight = 0:
```

--> change "**:**" to "**;**"

Answer (score 0):

No there is no rule against declaring variables after an echo statement

Comment: Could you expand a bit? I know you've technically answered the question that was asked, but you've not actually helped solve the issue that is really being addressed here. Do you have a way to solve OP's problem?